# If on right clicking on website and viewing the source code my json data is also getting shown. How would I prevent it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, json

the names of all cities can be seen in the source code through this code.
I am fetching the names of all cities from backened in `json` format and using with `angular js`.

Any other way to use json data with `angular js` without any `ajax` call.

```
var data=<?php echo $cities_name; ?>;
```

How would I prevent it from showing?

Comment: yeah did, but still showing.

Comment: If you don't want all the cities name to be available client side, why do you send it then???

Comment: @A. Wolff.  Then how would i fetch data in json and use it angular js. If I do it through http request the data can be viewed in firebug console and if do it through post I have to use it this way.

Comment: Your question is how can i hide some data send to client side from user? The answer is you cannot. If you want just to display only some specific data, then use any request to retrieve it, and only it... The logic should then be set server side regarding what data should be send back to client

Comment: Then how angular js deal with json data? Either through post or through http request, json data will be seen in any case.

Comment: WHAT you send to client is what he gets. What don't you understand?

Comment: I understand. then its bad to use angular as your data is not secured. right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with angularjs...

Comment: Why did you tag `jquery`?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is a client side language so you can't prevent to make it accesible from the source code.
One way to prevent that is use php to do your business logic instead of javascript